# Interact with webbrowser with vb button in vb.net using classes

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm just wondering how to have a send button implemented on the text input function i have already.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    WebBrowser1.Document.All("q").SetAttribute("value", TextBox5.Text)
```

So this so far takes the text from my text box and sends it to the web browser but I need it to search on the website as well.

The website I'm using doesn't have a tag name in the HTML code it only has a class, value and input type. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it this way

```
Dim elems As HtmlElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
For Each elem As HtmlElement In elems
    Dim nameStr As [String] = elem.GetAttribute("class")
    If nameStr IsNot Nothing AndAlso nameStr.Length <> 0 Then
        ele.InnerText = TextBox5.Text
    End If
Next
```

after you found the needed input field, you can search for the button and call this on the element

```
ele.InvokeMember("click")
```

Comment: There's no tag for input there's input type = button in the html. Is there a way to search for classes in the code

Comment: @Dilocho so you can search for the tag button and it's attribute class

Comment: stll not exactly what im looking for, Im looking to just get the attribute using ONLY class so i want soemthing like `code`webpagebrowser1.document.all("")getattribute(class)

Comment: @Dilocho so I still don't understand what the problem is. My suggested code will find all buttons and check they class attribute. You just have to check if nameStr is equals to the class value you are searching for

Comment: Im just not sure how to implement it. so it creates a new type of attribute for me to look through HTML in this case I want to locate the attribute "class" and whatever the class is equal to, eg "search_submit" it will look for it?

Comment: @Dilocho no, it creates nothing and yes, it will get the list of elements of type button, loop through the list, get the class attribute of each element and compare it to whatever you want. Just add needed check like AndAlso nameStr = "search_submit" ...